Add parent link for new work items, if link contains an item with a parent
A use case may be:

Feature is created

A child PBI is created

A new test case is created via - "Add link", "New item"


So most probably the test case is also a child of the feature so I wanted it linked in one go without extra clicks. Is that possible?
I know it's solved in some seconds but sometimes some hours are needed to reduce a second or two ;-)
Power automate may be an option, however I didn't find out how.

Hi @Marius Aberer, to automatically link the test cases to PBI's parent Feature, you can use Azure DevOps pipeline. Use webhook to monitor PBIs and trigger the Azure pipeline when new test case is linked to PBI. Then run REST API in Azure pipeline to link the test case to parent Feature.

According to Work link type,

A work item can have only one Parent. A parent work item can have many children.

The test case already has the PBI as its parent, so that it can't link the Feature as its parent. If you try to link it to the Feature manually, you will see the error "Work item {id} already has a Parent link so a new one cannot be added."
Child-Parent link is directional and is used to organize work item within a hierarchy. In your example, Feature is the grandparent of test case. If test case is also made the child of Feature, it will destroy the logical structure of Child-Parent link.

Update: The relation between PBI and test case is Tested By.
To automatically link the test cases to PBI's parent Feature, you can use Azure DevOps pipeline.

Create a webhook with “Work item updated” trigger.
Go to Project Settings -> Service Hooks -> Select Web Hooks -> Next.


Trigger on this type of event: Work item updated
Work item type: Product Backlog Item
URL: https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/{WebHookName}?api-version=6.0-preview. In my example, it's TestCaseAdd.


Create an Incoming WebHook Service connection
Go to Project Settings -> Service connections -> New Service connection -> Select Incoming WebHook.


WebHook Name: Your WebHook Name. The one you created in step1.
Service connection name: The name of your service connection.


Create a pipeline to link test cases to the Feature.

Use webhook to trigger Azure pipeline and filter based on the webhook response. Get the ids of the test case and PBI's parent.
Run REST API Work Items - Update to link the test case to Feature as a child.



The YAML of the pipeline:
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

resources:
  webhooks:
  - webhook: TestCaseAdd #Your WebHook name
    connection: WebhookTrigger #Your Incoming WebHook Service connation name
    filters:
    - path: resource['relations']['added'][*]['attributes']['name']
      value: 'Tested By'

variables:
  PBIId: ${{ parameters['TestCaseAdd']['resource']['workItemId'] }}
  ParentId: ${{ parameters['TestCaseAdd']['resource']['revision']['fields']['System.Parent'] }}

jobs:
- job: EchoVars
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo 'The PBIId is $(PBIId)'
      echo 'The ParentId is $(ParentId)'

  - ${{ each link in parameters.TestCaseAdd.resource.relations.added }}:
    - ${{ if eq(link.attributes.name, 'Tested By') }}:
      - script: |
          echo Test By Test Case - ${{ split(link.url, '/')[8] }}
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'Link Test Case to Feature'
        env:
          SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            $testCaseId = ${{ split(link.url, '/')[8] }}
            $headers = @{
                'Content-Type' = 'application/json-patch+json'
                'Authorization' = 'bearer ' + $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
            }
            $url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/_apis/wit/workitems/$(ParentId)?api-version=7.1"
            $body = "[        
              {
                `"op`": `"add`",
                `"path`": `"/relations/-`",
                `"value`": {
                  `"rel`": `"System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward`",
                  `"url`": `"https://dev.azure.com/yanghuan1/_apis/wit/workItems/$testCaseId`",
                  `"attributes`": {
                    `"comment`": `"Add a new child`",
                    `"name`": `"Child`"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]"
            Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method PATCH -Headers $headers -Body $body 

Note: Replace {OrgName} in PowerShell@2 task with your actual organization name.
Result: When you link a test case to a PBI with Tested By relation, the test case will be linked to PBI's parent as a child automatically.

Seems you misunderstood me:
I write it different:

Product Backlog: Linked to Test Case as Tested By relation. Parent: Feature 123
Testcase: Linked to PBI. Parent: Feature 123

I can set this relation in TWO steps, however I'd like to reduce a step

I understand it. The relation between PBI and test case is Tested By.  I have checked Power automate, but haven't found a solution. It may be possible to do it via Azure Pipeline using REST API, I will update you tomorrow.
